# Embedding Yammer Feed in SharePoint 2010 with IE 8 Document Standard

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, ie, yammer-embed

The issue is to embedd Yammer feed in my Sharepoint page which is running on latest version of IE 11 but with Document Standard set to IE8. I cannot change the Master page refrence of my Sharepoint site to IE-Edge compatibility as it will have issue with other related CSS on the sites. Currently it is set to IE-8

And as per my google research, Yammer feed is not supported in IE8 . So I would like to know any workaround on how to embedd yammer feed in a SharePoint page by forcing IE-edge for that particular framework or page?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Paul Tavares describes a hack for showing a page in IE8 mode: [How to render a SharePoint page in IE using Edge mode without changing the master page](https://paultavares.wordpress.com/2015/01/20/how-to-render-a-sharepoint-page-in-ie-using-edge-mode-without-changing-the-master-page/)

In summary, you upload an .aspx page to a document library, with a <meta> tag setting edge mode. The .aspx page will then load your other page in an iframe. IE can't run iframes in a different doc mode than the loading page, so once the page mode is set to edge, it stays edge.